# Query in Java - Subquery gone wrong or what?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm having a problem with this query of mine. I've spent almost an hour trying to correct it but still getting an error.

Heres my code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_case \n" +
                    "(Case_ID, Employee_ID, Patient_ID, Chief_Complaint, Date) \n" +
                    "VALUES \n" +
                    "(\n" +
                    "   '',\n" +
                    "   'EMP0001',\n" +
                    "   '(SELECT Patient_ID from tbl_patient WHERE ID_no = '"+getPatient_ID()+"')',\n" +
                    "   '"+txtcc.getText()+"',\n" +
                    "   '"+time+"'\n" +
                    ")";
                dp.sop("Query 'Create Case': "+sql);
                dp.Insertion(sql);
```

**Note**: `dp` stands for a class I inherited the methods from. `dp.Selection` is a simple executeQuery I made for retrieving data. `dp.Insertion` is for updating.

Here is the output of the query in String:

```
Query 'Create Case': INSERT INTO tbl_case 
(Case_ID, Employee_ID, Patient_ID, Chief_Complaint, Date) 
VALUES 
(
    '',
    'EMP0001',
    '(SELECT Patient_ID from tbl_patient WHERE ID_no = '10000201117')',
    'Head Ache',
    '2016-01-30 09:55:27'
)
```

and the error is a mysql syntax error near:

```
'10000201117)',
    'Head Ache',
    '2016-01-30 10:07:08'
)' at Line 7
```

anyone spotted whats wrong? I'm using mysql from xampp.

Comment: Could you show ```create table tble_case```? Is ```ID_no``` an integer?

Comment: Please please please use prepared statements to avoid [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @chris will do. this is just a school project but yes, we've been oriented about using concatination in sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `(SELECT Patient_ID from tbl_patient WHERE ID_no = '10000201117')` is in single quotes you might want to try putting 10000201117 in double quotes.

For example:

`'(SELECT Patient_ID from tbl_patient WHERE ID_no = "10000201117")'`

Comment: an error that would not occur with parameters. Concatenation is a lot of tail chasing. Who is that prof :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to surround the `SELECT` statement with quotes.
As it is now, this part `'(SELECT Patient_ID from tbl_patient WHERE ID_no = '` is interpreted as a value instead of part of a query.

Try: `(SELECT ...)` instead of `'(SELECT ...)'`